# Corsair Strafe not properly working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I have purchased a Corsair Strafe keyboard and here is what happens when I use it with Ubuntu PC:

It works fine when selecting entries from grub. Then it is again working properly while logging in. But it stops working when I get to desktop after successfully logging in. How can I fix it?

Since keyboard is not working inside system I don`t know how any further investigation be possible.

Here is the output of **lsusb**:

> `lsusb`
>
> [...]
>
> Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b15 Corsair
>
> [...]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed `ckb`? https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb. My RGB Strafe works fine.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Thanks for suggestion. It is totally safe to use?

Comment: It's perfectly safe.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Are there any prebuilt package for this tool or I have to follow the given instuctions on site? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before installation, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libudev-dev qt5-default zlib1g-dev libappindicator-dev
```

To install `ckb`, navigate to this page: https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb/releases

Download the .zip or tarball. Extract to a folder (doesn't matter). Navigate to that extracted folder. Double click the file called `quickinstall`, and follow the installer instructions.

Comment: Double clicking 'quickinstall' just opens the file in a text editor. I tried a sudo ./quickinstall and also chmod +x the file but not sure how to run this

Answer (score 1):

ckb referenced above is no longer actively maintained. The author recommends to use ckb-next

> This project is no longer maintained. I simply do not have the time to work on it anymore. Thanks to everyone who helped me to test and develop it.
>   An actively-developed version can be found here: https://github.com/mattanger/ckb-next

Answer (score 0):

The ckb Repository has moved yet again and can now be found at https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next

Comment: This answer is almost the same as another one.

Comment: The repo changed owner to avoid a single point of failure. Since Mattanger's account could go down i added the new location to make sure everyone interested in this project would find it.